# ¿Cómo usar el metodo DB::raw en Laravel con el paquete hyn multi-tenant?

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Laravel que hace uso del paquete Hyn para la conexión a múltiples bases de datos, estoy teniendo problemas para hacer uso del método raw de la fachada `Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB` dentro de un controlador.

En mi código, si ejecuto por ejemplo:

```
DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM Usuarios"))->get();
```

La consulta se realiza sobre la base de datos de system, ¿Hay alguna forma de usar esa fachada sobre la conexión del website que está actualmente cargado?

Answer (score 1):

Respondiendo a la pregunta, encontré que la fachada de Laravel por defecto va con la base de datos del .env, se puede cambiar a través de un seteo de configuración para indicar la BD a la cual apunta, pero leí que es mejor no hacerlo.

Ahora cómo logré ejecutar consultas: con hyn tenancy configurado, dentro de un controlador se puede hacer uso de `Hyn\Tenancy\Database\Connection`, luego obtener una instancia de la conexión que en mi caso es de tipo `Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection` y posteriormente acceder al objeto PDO de Doctrine, a través del cual se pueden realizar las consultas según se requiera.

El uso (de una manera muy simplificada) sería algo como esto:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Hyn\Tenancy\Database\Connection as TenancyConnection;

class ControladorEjemplo extends Controller 
{
    public function ejecutarSelect($queryString) {
        /* Obtener la instancia de hyn */
        $connection = app(TenancyConnection::class);
        /* Obtener el objeto de conexión */
        $tenantConnection = $connection->get();
        /* Obtener la instancia PDO de Doctrine */
        $pdoInstance = $tenantConnection->getPdo();

        /* Uso del objeto de Doctrine de acuerdo a documentación */
        $pdoStatement = $pdoInstance->prepare($queryString);
        $pdoStatement->execute();
        $queryResult = $pdoStatement->fetchAll(2);

        return $queryResult;
    }
}
```

Claramente se puede adaptar para aceptar parámetros bindeados o ejecutar inserts, update, etc siguiendo la documentación de Doctrine disponible en [Este enlace](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html)

Si alguien conoce otra forma de hacerlo o una vía más óptima sería bienvenida.